# Change Parent component based on Child props -> Preact/ React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I'm quite new to programming

In the example below, whenever child component renders null(...or in other words when getPosts() renders null), I want parent component div class to change from `className={style.container}` to `className={style.container.minimized}`.

What is the way to re-write this code to make this possible. Appreciate any help.

I have a Parent component like this

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <div className={style.root}>
            <div>
                <div className={style.container}>
                    <Child />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

My Child component is like this

```
const Child = () => {

     <div>
            {getPosts() ? (
                <div>
                    <p>Tomasz from {companyData.companyName}</p>
                    <p>{getPosts()}</p>
                </div>
            ) : null}
        </div>

}
```

Comment: In general in React, props pass down and callbacks would be used by the child to communicate to the parent. So you'd have a callback on the child prop that it invokes after loading that tells the parent which css class to use. However, be aware that re-rendering of the child when parent changes means you'd have to take care and possibly have to Memo. Another way to do it is to lift state up - if the parent needs to know how many posts there are, it gets that information and passes the collection to the child instead of the child doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the desired objective.

Presented below is one possible way:

**Parent**

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [hasPosts, setHasPosts] = React.useState(false);
    return (
        <div className={style.root}>
            <div>
                <div className={hasPosts ? style.container : style.container.minimized}>
                    <Child hasPosts={hasPosts} setHasPosts={setHasPosts} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Child**

```
const Child = ({hasPosts, setHasPosts, ...props}) => {
  // if getPosts() is an API, may choose to make the call
  // within useEffect hook. For simplicity, it is placed as-is below.
  const posts = getPosts();
  if (posts) setHasPosts(true);
  else setHasPosts(false);
  return (<div>
    {hasPosts ? (
      <div>
        <p>Tomasz from {companyData.companyName}</p>
        <p>{posts}</p>
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>);
};
```

**Explanation**

- Declare `hasPosts` and `setHasPosts` in parent (with useState hook)
- Pass both as props down to the child
- Make call to `getPosts()` in child and store result in local `posts`
- Invoke `setHasPosts` to set `hasPosts` to true if there are posts; otherwise to set it as false.
- Use `posts` within the child's JSX
- Use `hasPosts` in the parent's JSX and conditionally apply the appropriate style in the parent

PS: There are plenty of amazing resources on the internet that explain these details in a much more elegant and informative way.